# JPA - How to access query meta data?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am creating generic reporting logic for my application and want to be able to run any query and parse the responses. The inputs for the reporting are native SQL queries that I run using EntityManager.createNativeQuery(query).

I have all of this working fine, but currently I have to also indicate the return "headings" for the query response.

For example, for this query:

```
SELECT name, email FROM users;
```

I need to know that I'm getting back the name and email from the query. All I get back from running the query is a List of String arrays. Somehow, I'd like to be able to get back an array or list that has ["name", "email"] for this particular query.

I'm not seeing a way to interrogate the Query object to find out this information. I also don't see any indication of this data in the response. Is there a way to get at this data in JPA?

For specifics, the implementation I'm using is EclipseLink.

Thanks.

Comment: @ChadNC - How would I get a hold of that object through JPA, though? I understand that use of that object through JDBC, but can't get a handle to that kind of object through JPA.

Comment: What is the reason you are using jpa native queries instead of jdbc?

Comment: The rest of the application uses JPA (without native queries) so that's our current way into the database back end. I'm using native queries because I'm generating a bunch of reporting queries that essentially bring together data from multiple entities -- things like number of times a user has logged in, or how many objects a user created in the system. For this part, I don't want to have to write new code to handle a new report -- I just want to run the query and display the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EclipseLink also allows native queries to return Maps instead of Object[].

Use the "eclipselink.result-type" hint.

"eclipselink.result-type"="Map"

Answer (score 0):

Below query fetches the required fields from the database & set into the object using the appropriate constructor & return the list of objects.

```
SELECT NEW package_name.User(u.name,u.email) FROM User u;
```

This will return list of User objects instead of string arrays, in which name & email fields are set & remaining fields are set to their default values.

You have to pass only the fields that requires to be fetched, but have to provide constructor for that. In this case, for User class should have constructor for fields name, email.

Here you don't have to remember the field names, just fetch the required details from the object using accessor(get) methods.

Comment: I think my example was a little too simplified. Most of the queries I'll be doing for this section will span multiple entities. The Hint that James suggested is really the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With AspectJ you can get the info you want from the query.

Comment: I could see that working. We don't currently used aspect-oriented code, and I don't want to add it just for this, especially since I already have a working solution. The Hint that James suggested is really the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks for your help.